# Can't view an image in localhost

Tags: php, html

I changed my `*.html` file into `*.php`.  It seemed okay, but after I click the button for image it doesn't show the picture.  IN `*.html` file it was working.

### My code:

```
<img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\Bella Cristina/diamond.jpg" alt="Diamond Room" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
```

Comment: `<img src="Bella Cristina/diamond.jpg" alt="Diamond Room" style="width:200px;height:200px;">`

Try not to include "C:/xampp/htdocs/.."

it's should be a direct to your project forlder

Comment: Can you show us you full `PHP` code?

Comment: I think the code is missing. Please provide it

Comment: Provide the code - otherwise no one can't really help you.

Comment: I love it when they come running to Stack and asking for help, but don't bother responding to comments or answers for that matter. My *Spidey sense* is tingling as to what you're doing and NOT doing.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to make sure that the image exist in your image folder. Insert the name of the folder and the image into a field in your table in the database.

To display it write thees lines of PHP code:

```
    // this will display the image with the size reduced or increased by  180px by 180px
    echo '<img src="'.$row['field'].'" '.'width="180px"'.' '.'height="180px"'.'>';

    ?>
```

Note: the $connection much be existing in your connection string that is connecting the database